# Multiple Tags in URL query

Tags: php

I am going to be collecting tags that I want to pass in a url **can I just add spaces in between the tags** and then on the recieving php page I can parse out the tags

**If there are spaces in the url will I be able to explode it on the other end?**

URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/getinfo.php?tags=tag1 tag2 tag3&name=name1
```

and then on the php page I was thinking of parseing the tag variable

```
$tag_list = $_GET['tags'];

$tag_array = explode(" ", $tag_list);
```

Comment: Better structure: `/getinfo.php?tags[]=tag1&tags[]=tag2&tags[]=tag3`.  PHP will automatically build an array for you in `$_GET['tags']` if you use this URL.

Comment: Since I wont know the the number of tags I can just loop through and build my url. thanks@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should be properly encoded. You can do that with [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) function. As of space it should be replaced with either `+` or `%20`